# Loading and parsing data from file into array

Tags: c#, string, readfile

I am trying to load data from a DAT file into an array.

My data is composed of multiple rows in the following format:

`param_1::param_2::value`

I want to read this data in and convert it to a 2D-array (or other suitable format), so I will have:

`myData[param_1,param_2]=value`

Currently I am trying to read in the file into a an array of strings using StreamReader, but do not know how to convert the data from strings into the format I need.

This is the read part I'm using right now. What do I need to do to parse the data correctly?

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.dat");
        string strAllFile = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n\r", "\n");
        string[] arrLines = strAllFile.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, this `Linq` statement returns collection of `param1, param2, value` from each line in file.

```
var dataList = File.ReadAllLines("file.dat") // Read lines
        .Select(l=> l.Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.None)) // split each line
        .Select(l=> new 
               {
                  param1 = l[0],
                  param2 = l]1],
                  value  = l[2]
               })
        .ToList();
```

Now you can iterate list using

```
foreach(var item in dataList)
{
    // logic here.
    myData[item.param1,item.param2]=item.value

}
```

Comment: is the second .Select(...) supposed to be enclosed in the first .Select statement? There's a missing ')' somewhere...

Comment: Ahh... you are right, there was a missing bracket corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

if number of row and columns of  `myData` is known, you can simply write your function like this:

```
public void parseString(string[] lines)
{
    int[,] myData = new int[100, 100];
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        string[] data = s.Split("::");
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(data[1]);
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);

        myData[x, y] = value;
    }
}
```